# php script to push site backup into git repositry once per week

Tags: php, git, github, repository, sh

I want to create a php script which push my code into git repositry.

basically I need to run these three command

```
1 : git add -all
2 : git commit -m "code added"
3 : git push
```

Befoe running these command I have to go to that directory from where I want to push code. And when we push via git at that time we have to enter username and password, so I also need to manage that.

And I also need that this script should run automatically once per week.

How I do this.

Thanx

Comment: As stated below, you don't need PHP for this. You can do it in a bash script and use a cron job to run it once a week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont see the need to develop a php script for that.

you could just as well make a bash script and put it in a cron job that does this every week(which would handle the automation part)

as for the password part, i would suggest using ssh, and push it through that. you could add a ssh private key to your ssh config for github domain, and put your pulic key into github itself. that would handle the authorization

Comment: first create a executable file git.run.

Open a file named git.run in the directory /path/working_directory. Copy the below commands to the file and save it.

git add .


curtime=`date`


git commit -m "Automatic Backup @ $curtime"


git push origin master

Change the permissions of git.run to executable.

chmod +x git.run

for automation

crontab -e
It asks for your favourite editor. I use vim. Add the below entry to the file. (i for insert, esc + : + wq for save).


0 0 * * 0 cd /path/working_dir && ./git.run

is it ok or somthing more.

Comment: -you should change the push location to your repository's ssh location
-generate rsa public and private keys
-add your public key to github
-add your private key in your ssh config unger the github.com domain
-test if the script works without being invoked by a cronjob

Comment: I am new in shell scripting and github, so don't understand how I manage password part. I mean how I generate rsa public and private key.
Please could to let me know how I do this.

Comment: [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-generating-rsa-keys/) is an example of how to generate a key, and [here](https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996) is an example of how to install the ssh identity (host there can just be github.com and hostname the same), and [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) on how to change the remote url

Comment: Thanx, I am setting up this

Answer (score 0):

I was about to say the same thing!!! 
This is completely infra related tasks so php is not the language you should use since it is not its purpose. Prepare a shell script and configure your crontab for it. You can store the password in some variable/config file with specific privileges access or even better avoid using password authentication by using RSA keys based authentication.

Good luck!!!